# passing hidden input through post is not working (PHP and html)

Tags: php, html, forms

hi i am working on the following codes , it will take a value from a query and i want to pass the value of the variable to another php page that will do some statements .

this is my form:

```
  <form method="post" >    
   <input  type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $orderId; ?>"  />
     <button  type="submit" class="button" name="Reorder" value="Reorder">Reorder </button>
    </form>
```

here is the page that will receive the data and i will extract them from the form :

```
extract($_POST); 
$orderId=$_POST['id'];
```

This is the error :
Notice:  Undefined index: id

Comment: This wouldn't submit a user to another page. How are you sending the user to the page? Don't use `extract`.

Comment: @user3783243 i am not sending the user to another page , the second page will just get the data to do some statements , and since it is a form and i need to do something on it , it must to use a method like get or post

Comment: I don't follow. You contradict yourself in the comment, and in the body of the question. `i am not sending the user to another page` <> `the second page will just get the data`, nor `i want to pass the value of the variable to another php page`.. so there is only 1 page or 2 pages?? If 2 as you state multiple times how/when does the user get there?

Comment: in page 1 : the user will not enter any data he/she  will just click the button and in the second php page will receive the hidden input value to do some statements

Comment: How does the user get from page 1 to page 2? `Reorder` button wont send them anywhere

Comment: the button is working

Comment: `<form method="post" >` will not send the user anywhere. Are you sending the user to the next page with JS or how do they get there?

Comment: Anyway, It was a problem with my local server and i added an action in the form for the second page so everything goes well

Comment: The action you added is, precisely, the URL to the second page. That's what he was trying to explain to you.

Answer (score 1):

Your form doesn't have an action method. According to you, the data is being sent to another page.

```
action = "validate.php"
```

And you also didn't check whether the button `isset`.